# Fancy box image caption and count is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've recently updated my fancybox version to current v2.1.3. But after that in my fancybox gallery there was caption and image count is not working as it was. In my following code does that job but, it's not now working even though the current version given the same code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel=img_gallery]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my example gallery page [link](http://www.apartmentslanka.com/ztest_calender/hotel2.html). if you notice closely Image title caption is working in my gallery but not as expected. Actually my requirement is in [fancybox home page](http://fancybox.net/) there is a image gallery example on third. If you click on it you will get a image gallery popup with image caption and image count eg: 1/3 in black overlay. I just want simply apply that to my gallery. Could anyone please tell me how do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API options in fancybox v2.x are new and **not** compatible with previous versions (v1.3.x)

Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the right API options of the new version you are using.

To go faster, your code now should look like :

```
$("a[rel=img_gallery]").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'over'
        }
    },
    // helpers
    beforeShow: function() {
        this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
    } // beforeShow
}); // fancybox​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BP2Ew/)**

Comment: Thanks mac, your update really works great. Just for clarification to black overly should I give the width: 100%; is it OK?

Comment: @FazlulRahman : I guess it's up to you, however images only display either to fit on the screen or in their original size.